# Adding and multiplying columns of a numpy array with another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a `2D` `numpy` array `x` and and `1D` `numpy` array `y`:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(12).reshape((4, 3))
y = np.array(([1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0])
```

I want to multiply / add the column vector `y.reshape((4,1))` to each column of `x`. I attempted the following:

```
y1 = y.reshape((4,1))    
y1 * x
```

yields

```
array([[ 0., 1., 2.], 
       [ 6., 8., 10.], 
       [ 18., 21., 24.], 
       [ 36., 40., 44.]])
```

which is what I wanted. I also found

```
array([[ 1., 2., 3.], 
       [ 5., 6., 7.], 
       [ 9., 10., 11.], 
       [ 13., 14., 15.]])
```

with `y1 + x`.
I would like to know if there is a better (more efficient) way to achieve the same thing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NumPy supports this via broadcasting. Your code used broadcasting and it's the most efficient way to do things. I normally write it as:

```
>>> x * y[..., np.newaxis]
array([[  0.,   1.,   2.],
       [  6.,   8.,  10.],
       [ 18.,  21.,  24.],
       [ 36.,  40.,  44.]])
```

To see that it is equivalent:

```
>>> z =  y[..., np.newaxis]
>>> z.shape
(4, 1)
```

You can also see that NumPy doesn't copy any data, it just changes the iteration over the same memory internally

```
>>> z.base is y
True
```

Read more here

- http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html
- https://scipy-lectures.github.io/intro/numpy/operations.html#broadcasting

Answer (score 2):

You can use `np.add` and `np.multiply` :

```
>>> np.add(y1,x)
array([[  1.,   2.,   3.],
       [  5.,   6.,   7.],
       [  9.,  10.,  11.],
       [ 13.,  14.,  15.]])
>>> np.multiply(y1,x)
array([[  0.,   1.,   2.],
       [  6.,   8.,  10.],
       [ 18.,  21.,  24.],
       [ 36.,  40.,  44.]])
```

OR for in-place changing you can use `iadd` and `imul` methods of a numpy `ndarray` :

```
>>> x.__iadd__(y1)
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 5,  6,  7],
       [ 9, 10, 11],
       [13, 14, 15]])
>>> x = np.arange(12).reshape((4, 3))
>>> x.__imul__(y1)
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 6,  8, 10],
       [18, 21, 24],
       [36, 40, 44]])
```

But note that :

> In place operations will perform the calculation using the precision decided by the data type of the two operands, but will silently downcast the result (if necessary) so it can fit back into the array. Therefore, for mixed precision calculations, A {op}= B can be different than A = A {op} B. For example, suppose a = ones((3,3)). Then, a += 3j is different than a = a + 3j: while they both perform the same computation, a += 3 casts the result to fit back in a, whereas a = a + 3j re-binds the name a to the result.

Read more about [arithmetic-and-comparison-operations](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.ndarray.html#arithmetic-and-comparison-operations)