# Numpy multiplication of vectors of different size avoiding for loops

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I have a matrix, say, `P` of size `(X,Y)`. Also, I have two matrices, say, `Kx` and `Ky` of size `(M,N)` both, a matrix `pk` of size `(M,N)` and two vectors `u` and `v` of `X` and `Y` respectively. For example, they can be defined as follows:

```
import numpy as np
P = np.zeros((X,Y));
pk = np.random.rand(M,N);
Kx = np.random.rand(M,N);
Ky = np.random.rand(M,N);
u = np.random.rand(X);
v = np.random.rand(Y);
```

In the actual code they are not random, of course, but this shall not matter for this example. The question is, if there exists a pure numpy equivalent to the following:

```
for m in range(0, M):
    for n in range(0, N):
        for i in range(0,X):
            for j in range(0,Y):
               Arg = Kx[m,n]*u[i] + Ky[m,n]*v[j];
               P[i,j] += pk[m,n]*np.cos(Arg);
```

All `M`,`N`,`X`,`Y` are different, but `X` and `Y` can be the same if the solution does not exist otherwise.

Comment: "two vectors v and u of X and Y respectively": do you have `u` and `v` swapped there?

Comment: @EugeneB here's how you can ake your question clearer: It is much better to describe the quantities `P`, `Kx`, `Ky` and `pk` with a few lines of code than with a paragraph of text. And it would be even better for people trying to help you if you can edit the code in your question so that it actually runs without needing any editing or guesswork. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29087701/553404) for an example and [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29864176/553404) for some advice.

Comment: Thank you, edited for convenience.

Comment: @EugeneB have you tried running this code?

Comment: Yes, I have. It works perfectly with values I am interested in as well as with random or any other entries.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A common strategy for eliminating `for-loop`s in NumPy calculations is to work with higher-dimensional arrays.

Consider for example, the line

```
Arg = Kx[m,n]*u[i] + Ky[m,n]*v[j]
```

This line depends on the indices `m`, `n`, `i` and `j`. *So `Arg` depends on `m`, `n`, `i` and `j`*. This means `Arg` can be thought of as a 4-dimensional array indexed by `m`, `n`, `i` and `j`. So we can eliminate the 4 `for-loops` -- as far as `Arg` is concerned -- by computing

```
Kxu = Kx[:,:,np.newaxis]*u
Kyv = Ky[:,:,np.newaxis]*v
Arg = Kxu[:,:,:,np.newaxis] + Kyv[:,:,np.newaxis,:]
```

`Kx[:,:,np.newaxis]` has shape `(M, N, 1)`, and `u` has shape `(X,)`. Multiplying them together uses [NumPy broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to create an array of shape `(M, N, X)`. Thus, above, [new axes are used somewhat like placeholders](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing), so that `Arg` ends up with 4 axes indexed by `m`,`n`,`i`,`j` in that order.

Similarly, `P` can be defined as

```
P = (pk[:,:,np.newaxis,np.newaxis]*np.cos(Arg)).sum(axis=0).sum(axis=0)
```

The `sum(axis=0)` (called twice) sums along the `m` and `n` axes, so that `P` ends up being a 2-dimensional array indexed by `i` and `j` only.

By working with these 4-dimensional arrays, we get to apply NumPy operations on whole NumPy arrays. In contrast, when using the 4 `for-loops`, we had to do computations value-by-value on scalars. Consider for example what `np.cos(Arg)` is doing when `Arg` is a 4-dimensional array. This off-loads the computation of *all* the cosines in one NumPy function call which does the underlying loop in compiled C code. This is much much faster than calling `np.cos` once for each scalar. This is the reason why working with the higher-dimensional arrays ends up being so much faster than the `for-loop`-based code.

---

```
import numpy as np

def orig(Kx, Ky, u, v, pk):
    M, N = Kx.shape
    X = u.size
    Y = v.size
    P = np.empty((X, Y), dtype=pk.dtype)
    for m in range(0, M):
        for n in range(0, N):
            for i in range(0,X):
                for j in range(0,Y):
                   Arg = Kx[m,n]*u[i] + Ky[m,n]*v[j]
                   P[i,j] += pk[m,n]*np.cos(Arg)
    return P

def alt(Kx, Ky, u, v, pk):
    Kxu = Kx[:,:,np.newaxis]*u
    Kyv = Ky[:,:,np.newaxis]*v
    Arg = Kxu[:,:,:,np.newaxis] + Kyv[:,:,np.newaxis,:]
    P = (pk[:,:,np.newaxis,np.newaxis]*np.cos(Arg)).sum(axis=0).sum(axis=0)
    return P

M, N = 10, 20
X, Y = 5, 15
Kx = np.random.random((M, N))
Ky = np.random.random((M, N))
u = np.random.random(X)
v = np.random.random(Y)
pk = np.random.random((M, N))
```

---

Sanity check, (showing alt and orig return the same result):

```
In [57]: P2 = alt(Kx, Ky, u, v, pk)

In [58]: P1 = orig(Kx, Ky, u, v, pk)

In [59]: np.allclose(P1, P2)
Out[59]: True
```

---

A benchmark, showing  `alt` is significantly faster than `orig`:

```
In [60]: %timeit orig(Kx, Ky, u, v, pk)
10 loops, best of 3: 33.6 ms per loop

In [61]: %timeit alt(Kx, Ky, u, v, pk)
1000 loops, best of 3: 349 µs per loop
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast and detailed reply! Seems that this is what I've been looking for!